# Misunderstanding the difference between Map Apply (@@@) and Map (/@)

Tags: list-manipulation

Here's a minimal working example of a problem I'm having:

```
FindInstance[#, {a, b}] & @@@ {{a + b > 1, a + b < 2}, {a + b > 2, a + b < 3}}
(*{{{a -> 0, b -> 2}}, {{a -> 0, b -> 3}}}*)
```

Obviously this is not what I'm after, as $a+b<2$ is not satisfied in the first and $a+b<3$ is not satisfied in the second case. Individually they work fine:

```
FindInstance[{a + b > 1, a + b < 2}, {a, b}]
(*{{a -> 0, b -> 3/2}}*)
```

And:

```
FindInstance[{a + b > 2, a + b < 3}, {a, b}]
(*{{a -> 0, b -> 5/2}}*)
```

I'm guessing my issue is something to do with the evaluation order. Or maybe it's only reading the first inequality in each constraint list? What am I missing here?

**EDIT: I've changed the title to reflect the error in my understanding.**

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Should I delete the question?

Comment: Shane, unless things have changed the existence of a positively-voted answer means you will be unable to delete your own question.  But there is no need for that.  For the most part duplicates are not deleted; they serve as useful entry points from search engines that redirect to the original.  Incidentally it is probably best not to think of `@@@` as "Map Apply" as `Map` is not involved.  Either function (`Map` or `Apply`) can be specified to operate at any level or contiguous range of levels within an expression.  `@@@` is `Apply` with a *levelspec* of `{1}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
FindInstance[#, {a, b}]& /@ {a + b > 1 && a + b < 2, a + b > 2 && a + b < 3}
```

or, in fact, this:

```
FindInstance[#, {a, b}]& /@ {{a + b > 1, a + b < 2}, {a + b > 2, a + b < 3}}
```

Comment: You're right. I'm just getting confused between Map and Apply like an idiot! I can keep my constraints in list form, though, and just use /@ in place of @@@. Thanks! (I'll accept when it lets me)

Comment: Yeah you're right. Just edited the answer to reflect this.